# How to access ajax response data as html with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, response

Imagine, there are two files

1. test.php
2. index.php

In test.php there are only a html button with id click.

In index.php there are also only a html button with id send.

If I send an ajax request to test.php file from index.php then the button with id click from test.php should be inserted within a div in index.php. Now I want this button to hide p element when it is clicked within index.php.

Note: onclick attribute should not come with #click button.

How to do that?
I am currently using android phone to ask this question. So I am not able to write the question with examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#id").live("click",function() {
 alert("hai");
})
```

EDIT

```
$("#id").on("click",function() {
   alert("hai");
})
```

OR

```
$("#id").delegate("click",function() {
   alert("hai");
})
```

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and removed in 1.9. You shouldn't be recommending it, use `.on()`.

Comment: @KirenSiva so please consider fixing your answer!

Comment: None of these work anyway. They rely on the element being present. (Well, `delegate` *might* work, but I've never used it in favour of `$(someParentElement).on("click", ".selector", function(){...});`...)